# NullPointerException в onCreateOptionsMenu Android

Tags: java, android

Всем доброй ночи!! Не могу сообразить почему хватаю `NullPointerException`   в   `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Реализую обычный `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener` и тут эксепшн. Это часть из чужого кода, но там все прекрасно работает.

код:

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);


// Вот тут вылетаю!!! Всмысле в первой строке после этого текста. 
    searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {  

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

        }
    });

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String searchQuery) {
            adapterForListViewMainActivity.filter(searchQuery.toString().trim());
            listViewMainActivity.invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

stack trace:

```
05-28 09:48:19.333 1407-1407/com.vitaliylevashov.finalvariant D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-28 09:48:19.333 1407-1407/com.vitaliylevashov.finalvariant W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa621b908)
05-28 09:48:19.341 1407-1407/com.vitaliylevashov.finalvariant E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.vitaliylevashov.finalvariant.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:698)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:407)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.doInvalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:769)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:201)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    05-28 09:48:19.357 411-845/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.vitaliylevashov.finalvariant/.MainActivity
    05-28 09:48:19.825 411-845/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3622K, 30% free 9255K/13160K, paused 11ms, total 13ms
```

Comment: На какой строчке? Приложите `stacktrace` ошибки.

Comment: action_search точно содержит action view SearchView?

Comment: Попробуйте перенести весь код с SearchView в `onPrepareOptionMenu` - возможно просто вьюха не успела отрисоваться.

Comment: И так тоже крешится....

Comment: Вроде пошло. У меня мое Activity наследовало ListActivity заменил на AppCompatActivity